# Adding basic authentication to a simple HTML href link

Tags: html, download, href, smartgwt

i am using smartGWT, and i want to download a file from the server, by sending a request using href link , but to download the file i need basic authentication , so is it possible to add basic authentication to a simple html href ?

the href link looks like this

```
String exportLink =  "<A href=\"" +restlet/api/user/getUsers +  "\"" + constants.HREF_STYLE + ">"+Download+"</A>";
```

Answer (score 4):

Your link need to have the following form:

```
https://username:password@example.com/path
```

After clicking on this link, the browser will user the given username+password to authenticate itself to the server. Please have in mind, that you publish the username+password to the user.

*Update:* See the comment by Yvonne: The above URL scheme is not supported any more by Chrome and IE.

Comment: The http://username:password@example.com format is no longer supported by either IE or Chrome, wouldn't be surprised if others followed suit if they haven't already.

Answer (score -1):

Use server side authentication.

Get the information form user HTTP session and check whether user is authorized to download the file or not? Send an error page or proper message to the client if user is not authorized to access the file.

> I want to download a file from the server, by sending a request using href link.

I have already answered this on your question [SmartGWT handling file in the response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977965/smartgwt-handling-file-in-the-response-body)